# JSON.parse failing

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm trying to create a JavaScript object from a JSON string "object" but it  fails with the error:

"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 48 of the JSON data"

```js
var jsobj = JSON.parse( '{"lineID":11,"siteID":3,"mystring":"this is a \"Test\" string with quotes"}' );
```

**mystring** is a string which includes double quotes but I've escaped them correctly with the backslash. Why would it fail?

I noticed it passes OK on this online JSON parsing site: [json parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\` character is an escape character for JavaScript **and** JSON.

When the JavaScript parser parses the string literal it turns `\"` in the JavaScript source code into `"` in the string.

When the JSON parser parses the string, it finds an unescaped `"` and errors.

To include `\"` in the JSON data, you need to escape the `\` in the JavaScript string literal: `\\"`.

```js
var jsobj = JSON.parse('{"lineID":11,"siteID":3,"mystring":"this is a \\"Test\\" string with quotes"}');
console.log(jsobj);
```

---

Nesting data formats is always a pain. It is best to avoid doing that whenever possible.

It doesn't make sense to have a string literal containing JSON in JavaScript in the first place.

JSON is a subset of JavaScript. Just use the JSON as a JavaScript literal.

```js
var jsobj = {
  "lineID": 11,
  "siteID": 3,
  "mystring": "this is a \"Test\" string with quotes"
};

console.log(jsobj);
```

Comment: Many thanks Quentin! That's horrible - but obvious now you've explained it :-) BTW I take your point but I'm generating this code serverside it's a way to convert a .NET object to a JavaScript object with minimal hassle. I'm using JSON.SerializeObject(myObj) on the server which can convert any simple C# object to JSON and then using JSON.parse on the client to convert the serialised object to a JavaScript object. With your solution I should now be able to get that to work with minimal effort :-)

Answer (score 0):

For double quotes you have to use double  backslash

```
var jsobj = JSON.parse( '{"lineID":11,"siteID":3,"mystring":"this is a \\"Test\\" string with quotes"}' );
```

this should work